# accessing types within a type union

Tags: julia

Suppose I have a DataFrame in Julia and `typeof((df[:,:col]))` returns `Array{Union{Missing, Float64},1}`. How do I check the types within `Union{Missing, Float64}` to, for example, see if `Float64` is in that Union, or to make sure that there are no `String` values in that Union?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the subtype operator:

```
T1 = Union{Missing, Float64}
Float64 <: T1 # true
String <: T1  # false
```

This is because Float64 is a subtype of the union, whereas String is not (since it's not in the union).

If you're defining a method to dispatch on it, you could go a step further:

```
function doSomething(arr::Vector{Union{Missing, T}}) where T <: Float64
    # do something
end
```